# How to hide a text label after mouse is pressed?

Tags: processing, control-p5

I have  used `Control-P5` library for drawing the `text label`

```
  void setup(){
    size(1400,800);
    cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
    myTextlabelB = new Textlabel(cp5,"Hello world",100,100,400,200);
 }

 void draw(){
    myTextlabelB.draw(this); 
    if(mousePressed){ 
        myTextlabelB.hide();
   // I want to hide the label here, but the hide function doesn't work
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some bug with hiding `Textlable` but it is working with `Label` class so you just need to get the `label` part and then hide it:

```
myTextlabelB.get().hide();
```

Also it is important to redraw your background at the beginning of the `draw()` function

```
background(0);
```